# Data packets from tritech micron sonar

Tags: python

How does one find the data packets from a tritech micron sonar for interfacing with a raspberry pi
Code for interfacing would be appreciated.

Connecting the tritech micron sonar to a PC does not give any indication to the data packets

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @D.L how do we get to know what type of data packets is being sent by the tritech micron sonar? 
Without knowing the type of data which tritech micron sonar is sending we cannot interface it with the raspberry pi 4